# How to parse xml statement with tags inside the text

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

How can I parse the following in python to get the text between the `<p>` brackets but without the `<mark>` tag or value? Preferably using ElementTree functionality

```
<plist>
<p>Hello there? <mark type="ph"/> How are you?</p>
</plist>
```

Parsing the following should return 'Hello There? How are you?

Thanks!

Comment: Also should note that this xml is part of a larger block so it would be nice if it was easily iterable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse XML in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)

Comment: @John I don't think this one is a duplicate. The question might lack the attempts to solve the problem, but, in general, the question is clear and about a specific use case. Thanks.

Comment: I did attempt to solve, just didn't include them. I tried putting in a clause checking for the mark tags, however, locating them didn't allow me to parse without them. In addition, if I attempted to just use ElementTree .text functionality but that cuts the string off at the mark tag.

Answer (score 1):

In case of [`lxml.etree`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html), you can use `string()` XPath function:

```
from lxml.etree import fromstring

data = """
<plist>
<p>Hello there? <mark type="ph"/> How are you?</p>
</plist>
"""

root = fromstring(data)
for p in root.xpath("//plist/p"):
    print p.xpath("string()")
```

Print:

```
Hello there?  How are you?
```

Comment: I considered this but was hoping to limit my dependencies to just ElementTree. Is there any other alternatives you know of?

Comment: @JJJ1106 you may solve it with `xml.etree.ElementTree`, but it would not be as concise and simple as it is with `lxml.etree` since there is only limited XPath support provided. Why don't use what is there in the Python ecosystem to solve the problem?

Comment: Good point, so because I have iterated down to this point in my xml, using a starting node and working my way down the hierarchy, can this string() from lxml.etree function work on element object type? Or do I have to turn it into a string first?